# Сравнение файлов

Tags: файлы, php

Ребята сталкивался ли кто-то с задачей сравнения двух файлов? При этом необходим наиболее оптимальный вариант в плане быстродействия, а также возможность получения данных о проценте совпадения одного файла с другим.

В данный момент рассматриваю два варианта решения данной проблемы.

1. Получаем **sha1 хеш** файлов и сравниваем. Оптимален в плане скорости обработки файлов но нельзя получить реальный процент совпадения файлов.
2. Получаем тело файлов через **file_get_contents** и сравниваем с помощью функции **similar_text($file1, $file2, $percent);**. Вариант рабочий но быстродействие данного метода не внушает доверия.

Буду рад услышать другие вариации решения данной задачи. Возможно есть уже готовые решения что также будет интересно услышать.

Comment: читаете файл блоками(допустим 1к) и сравниваете хэш блоков
размер блока стоит выбирать исходя из размера файла, и необходимой точности, для точности в 1% стоит брать размер блока = 1\100 размера файла и округлять до степени двойки.

Comment: идею понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Linux diff. Сравнивает файлы без велосипедов.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, посмотрю еще в эту строну.

Answer (score 0):

Python идеален для работы с файлами

```
import filecmp
import sys

if filecmp.cmp(argv[0], argv[1]):
    print u"Равны"
else:
    print u"Не равны"
```

Для запуска скрипта в PHP используй

```
shell_exec('python /path/to/myScript.py file1 file2')
```

Comment: 1. Вызывать из PHP-скрипта Python-скрипт - редкостное извращение.
 2. Просмотрите [исходники модуля `filecmp`][1]. В частности функцию `cmp`. Убедитесь, что сравнение происходит по алгоритму "сравниваем сигнатуры файлов, пытаемся найти результат сравнения в кэше, поочерёдно считываем блоки файлов и сравниваем их пока не наткнёмся на различия". Перечитайте вопрос. Подумайте, будет ли этот способ быстрее уже предложенных.


  [1]: http://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.3.2/filecmp_8py_source.html